# How to write null characters to a bytea column using psycopg2 in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, bytea

I'm trying to write binary data into `bytea` column in PostgreSQL table. My data contains null characters and I get following error.

```
ValueError: A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters.
```

This is my code.

```
import numpy as np
fft = [0.0, 0.2, 0.0215]
[float(i) for i in fft]
blob = struct.pack('%sd' % np.size(fft), *fft)
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO fft (id, v) VALUES(%s, %s)""", ("widget_fft", blob))
```

`id` is of type `text` and `v` is of type `bytea`.

I have also tried using `psycopg.Binary(blob)`, but it inserts backslashes which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, you have to use the `psycopg2.Binary` wrapper:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO fft (id, v) VALUES(%s, %s)""",
            ("widget_fft", psycopg2.Binary(blob)))
```

See [the documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-binary) for details.

This is not required in Python 3.

I tried it and didn't see any backslashes. Can you show what exactly is in `blob`?

Comment: well, it turns out there's no issue with the psycopg2. I was building the blob using struct.pack, which gives output as a string. When I changed that string to a bytearray, the problem went away.